# Almost sure convergence of recursive martingale

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $\xi_n$ be a sequence of independent Bernoulli random variables with $\mathbb{P}(\xi_n= \alpha_n)= p_n$ and $\mathbb{P}(\xi_n=-1) = q_n$ where $p_n + q_n = 1$ and $\alpha_n = \frac{q_n}{p_n}$. Define $X_n$ recursively

$X_n = X_{n-1} + (X_{n-1}+1)\xi_n$

Assume that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty q_n = \infty$. Show that $X_n$ converges to $-1$ almost surely. Does it converge in $L^1$?

I can check that if $\xi_n = -1$ then I have $X_n = X_{n-1} + (X_{n-1}+1)(-1) = -1$. So in order to obtain that $\mathbb{P}(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}X_n = -1)$ I have to show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\alpha_n = -1$.

I know that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\alpha_n = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{q_n}{1-q_n}$. How can I proceed from here?

Comment: $\alpha_n$ is non-negative (ratio of probabilities), how can you ask for $\lim \alpha_n = -1$? As a hint, observe two things about the process - if $\xi_n = -1$ then $X_n = -1$ and if $X_n = -1$ then $X_m = -1$ for all $m > n$ irrespective of $\xi_i$ for $i > n$ - basically there's a small chance of the process dying to $-1$ at each step. This immediately suggests working with the stopping time $\tau:= \inf\{n : \xi_n = -1\}$, i.e. the time at which the process collapses.

Comment: So I have to show that $\mathbb{P}(T<\infty) = 1$?